# Can Ubuntu provide an IDE for C, C++ programming?

Tags: application-development, c, ide

I am a beginner in the field of programming. I have tried to learn C and C++ on a Windows 7 computer using the Turbo C++ compiler, but faced frequent failures and finally my laptop's motherboard failed. Please guide me so that can I install Ubuntu on my Windows 7 computer. Can Ubuntu provide a built-in IDE for C, C++ programming, and if not, what is the solution for my problem on Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, I personally use eclipse but there ore lots of others.

Answer (score 4):

#### Edit:

In addition to my answer below, I'd like to add point out that the [Netbeans C++ edition](https://netbeans.org/features/cpp/) is a very nice IDE too. At the time when I wrote my answer, I haven't considered looking at this because I only knew it from Java development, and for this I use Jetbrains IDEA. A bit later I tried Netbeans for a C++ project and it turned out to be very helpful and intuitive.

---

For the first part of your question about installing on a Win7 machine, please read on the [official ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). It is explained how you can create a dual system with Windows and Ubuntu.

For your second question: Yes, Ubuntu and Linux in general is excellent for C/C++ development. You have several choices if you want an IDE instead of a simple editor. I personally like [Eclipse with C++ support](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/), but you have several other choices

- [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) is a very nice C++ IDE
- [Qt Creator](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category:Tools::QtCreator) which can be used for development in general and not only for Qt applications
- Anjuta is another one I tried long time ago which was quite nice..

Please find a long [list of available IDE's here](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Entwicklungsumgebungen) (although it's in German, you surly can read this).

Please note that especially Eclipse, Code::Blocks and QT Creator is **not** restricted to Ubuntu. You can try them in Windows too!